# Find out what template is used for page on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working in a multisite wpml environment with multiple php templates. I have created categories and the search widget shows up on all categories except for the product category. I need to find out what template in wordpress a specific category page is using. The page is http://vn.isafyi.com/category/products/. Is there a something I can add to the functions file to display the template that url is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress keeps the path to the current template in the global `$template` variable.

```
function display_template_path() {
    global $template;
    echo '<pre class="debug">';
    echo $template;
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'display_template_path' );
```

Comment: Awesome, this works, I see now that my page is using the wrong php template. It is using category.php but should be using category-product.php. Do you know which file this is set in?

Comment: WordPress parses the query and figures out which template to use according to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Check that the "Product" category has the expected slug.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin this should do your work done:
[What Template File Am I Viewing?](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-template-file-am-i-viewing/)

Answer (score 0):

Its should be category-product-type.php page and then track down the code from there. See this for more help:

[Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)